# What is the difference between “Raspbian” Bullseye and “Debian” Bullseye

Tags: raspbian, debian

Just ran “cat /etc/os-release’ on my two Pi 4Bs and noticed one uses Raspbian Bullseye and the other says Debian Bullseye. I used the same official Raspberry Pi imager but likely updated the imager in between. Just curious if there are any differences besides the names in os-release. [image: Pi A]

[image: Pi B]

Comment: The output of ‘ dpkg --print-architecture’ is one difference. Debian uses arm64 while Raspbian uses armhf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Raspberry Pi OS* was originally based on the armhf implementation of *Raspbian* which is a 32bit ARM6 OS which will run on all Pi up to but excluding Pi5.

The 64bit OS (which was introduced in Feb 2022) is based on the normal *Debian* upstream (although with a few Raspberry Pi Ltd. modifications) which will only run on the later model Pi. Except for these it uses normal Debian binaries for most of its code.